# How to ask someone about my position in a waiting list?

Tags: sentence-construction, interrogatives

Suppose that your name is in a waiting list. Now you want to know how many persons are ahead of you. How would you ask that? Does it make any sense to say something like:

> Would you tell me how my position is in the waiting-list now?

Consider that the waiting list is a ranked list prioritized according to the time people submitted their request.

Comment: I would say "How many people are ahead of me?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring situations where you might need to put the question in a more delicate way, and situations where the waiting list is not a ranking but a pool:

> Where am I on the waiting list?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The list is a ranked list prioritized according to the time they submitted their requests.

Comment: The answer I've given fits that case.

Comment: @Cardinal  this is sometimes called a "queue" instead of a "waiting list", but the expression is the same, *"Where am I in the queue?"*